# Reaper 5.23 One Track Controls All others

Tags: reaper

I have a simple project--4 tracks. The mute button on the first track controls all the other tracks.

In other words, if Track 1 is unmuted, I can mute/unmute tracks 2-4. But, if Track 1 is muted--all tracks are muted--pressing the mute/unmute button on other tracks does nothing--they all remain greyed out in the track area.

If I delete track 1, all tracks are deleted--it is as if the tracks are grouped, but they are not grouped.

If i hover over Track one on the left side stack of tracks, it says Track 1 (folder): [ Name of Track ] --is that a clue? If I hover over the other tracks, it doesn't say (folder) it just says the track name

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You have configured track one as a folder track and the other three are in the track-one folder. You can drag the other 3 tracks out of the folder to the top level and they should start behaving as you would expect.